# Awaiting foreign tasks - warning VSTHRD003

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

Lets say I have a startable class that have StartAsync and StopAsync. When StopAsync is called the method wait until are necessary tasks are finished and handled properly (Writing some things to db etc that cannot be so easily canceled and can take time). I thought creating a task in the class and
pass it to the StopAsync is fine but according to VisualStudio.Threading not and it can cause a deadlock.

To simulate the situation I have this example class:

```
class Startable
{
    private Task _runningTask;

    public Task StartAsync()
    {
        _runningTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
        return Task.Completed;
    }

    public Task StopAsync()
    {
        return _runningTask;
    }
}
```

I'm using in my app Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading nuget that generates warning [VSTHRD003](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD003.md).
My question is what is the proper way how to handle this situation when I need to wait until a task created from a random thread context is finished? In my case, the app is a console app in 8.0 Net so I guess the deadlock shouldn't happen but still I'm curious how I should do this.

Comment: It sounds like you're making a background worker process. Have you seen how it's done with a Hosted Service in ASP.NET? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

`VisualStudio.Threading` was originally designed for Visual Studio extensions. While several types in this library are useful in other apps, there are parts of the library design that assume you are writing a Visual Studio extension.

In this case, the warning doesn't apply to you. There is no main UI thread and (AFAICT) no need for a joinable task factory in a console application.

Comment: Hi Stephen! Would you advise turning off all the warnings and analyzers coming with the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading` package, when using it for a project that is NOT a Visual Studio extension?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the analyzers for that package to say. I'd probably leave them on by default and just disable ones that get in the way.

Comment: Thanks a lot @StephenCleary and gunr2171. I've thought that just want to assure myself. Thanks to gunr2171 comment I also found this link from microsoft which basically do the same (in a better way). https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice